# Auto Regex for this Format

Tags: regex, notepad++

ME4YOU13

i need

Me4you13

how to do that win Notepad++

Comment: Whose username and password is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow regex to find your text:

`(.)(.+)` : It capture any char at first group, and the follow chars as second group.

And replace by:

`\U$1\L$2` : It makes the first group uppercase and the second group lower case.

[image]

Hope this helps,